# add maven dependency of another project

Tags: maven, dependencies, project, external

Im developing a web application in a maven project. I also have a second project (no web) that contains some classes that my web maven project needs. So, I need to add a dependency in the pom.xml file of my second project, but I don't know how to do it.

Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit more details? multi module build ?

Comment: For example. I have a project X that have some classes that do some operations. Then, I have a project A that will use classes from project X. It would be done easy by importing the project X to project A, but I need to do this using maven. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution is to use a dependency

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>x.y.z</groupId>
    <artifactId>project-X</artifactId>
    <version>X.z.Z</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```